# Test C# code without building my application

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm trying some string manipulation in my web app, but I don't want to compile the whole application just to see the result something simple.

Is there a (preferably free) tool I can use to do quick tests, or is there something in VS2008 I can use?

Thanks

Comment: This should be easy with NUnit (or some other framework) if you have the the project appropriately broken into assemblies.  If the code is in your front end assembly, you will need to rebuild.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'll look into NUnit, but for now LINQPad is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're just looking to try out a few statements in immediate mode, LINQpad is great for writing short snippets.

[LINQPad Homepage](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: +1 also for LINQPad (although the creator needs to market it differently)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php)

Visual Studio 2008 has some [built in unit test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147(VS.80).aspx) capability.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to test a piece of code without building/running the whole application is *unit tests*. There are several frameworks helping you to do this.

For C#, I have used [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/).

Comment: As always, I'd be interested to learn why this got voted down.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [unit testing framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147.aspx) that comes bundled with VS2008.

Note: You'll still have to build whatever project contains the code -- you can't get around that -- but you won't have to build the whole solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to test functionalities like this with unit tests. I don't know C#, but there must be many frameworks and/or libs.

Answer (score 0):

If the string you want to change is in the ASPX page it's self you can just edit the page and save it.  A simple refresh should update the results.  If it is a variable value you should be able to use the [Watch Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869(VS.71).aspx) to change the value.

If you want a programmatic solution for testing a method you can either use the built in [MSTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625(VS.80).aspx), a simple custom console app, or one of the other unit test frameworks.